# libsensors5 or libsensors-config upgrade problem

Tags: package-management, 19.04, sensors, held-packages

After upgrading my Ubuntu from 18.10 to 19.04 some packages were held back but I didn't really care since I thought the issues will be resolved in a few weeks when dependencies will be upgradeable to proper versions for my OS. After a while that didn't happen and I've poked around these "held back" packages and see a problem, that also explains why my system load indicator widget and other sensors dependent widgets stopped working.

There are only 2 packages left that are held back: `libsnmp30 sysstat`. Both depend  in one way or the other on `libsensors5` which in turn depends on `libsensors-config`. Now I could try installing `libsensors-config` via `sudo apt install libsensors-config` but the (last) output that I get makes me think that's not a good idea, right?

```
$ sudo apt install sysstat
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 sysstat : Depends: libsensors5 (>= 1:3.5.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

```
$ sudo apt install libsensors5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libsensors5 : Depends: libsensors-config but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

```
$ sudo apt install libsensors-config
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas acl activity-log-manager aglfn apg appmenu-qt apt-config-icons-large apt-config-icons-large-hidpi apturl-common argyll argyll-ref bamfdaemon blender-data breeze-cursor-theme breeze-gtk-theme calculix-ccx catdoc cheese-common cinnamon-desktop-data cinnamon-l10n colord-data debconf-kde-data docbook-xml
  docbook-xsl epstool evolution-data-server-common fonts-dejavu fonts-dejavu-extra fonts-freefont-otf fonts-hack fonts-noto-hinted fprintd freecad-common freecad-runtime gdal-data geoclue geoclue-ubuntu-geoip gir1.2-accounts-1.0 gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-gcr-3 gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-gdm-1.0
  gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 gir1.2-gweather-3.0 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-nm-1.0 gir1.2-nma-1.0 gir1.2-signon-1.0 gir1.2-totemplparser-1.0 gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 gist gjs gkbd-capplet gnome-calculator gnome-control-center-faces gnome-screensaver gnome-session-common gnome-todo-common gnome-video-effects
  gnuplot-data grilo-plugins-0.3-base gvfs-libs haveged hddtemp hdf5-helpers hplip-data hwdata ibverbs-providers ieee-data indicator-appmenu indicator-datetime indicator-keyboard indicator-messages indicator-power indicator-printers indicator-session indicator-sound inxi jayatana kactivities-bin kate5-data kde-cli-tools-data
  kde-style-qtcurve-qt4 kdelibs5-data kdeplasma-addons-data kdiff3-doc kdoctools5 khotkeys-data kio-extras-data kpackagetool5 ktexteditor-data ktorrent-data kwayland-data kwin-data libaccounts-glib0 libaccounts-qt5-1 libaec-dev libaec0 libappstreamqt2 libaribb24-0 libarmadillo9 libarpack2 libattica0.4 libbamf3-2
  libbasicusageenvironment1 libblas-dev libblosc1 libboost-program-options1.67.0 libboost-python1.67.0 libboost-regex1.67.0 libbrotli1 libcaf-openmpi-3 libcamel-1.2-62 libcddb2 libcdio-cdda2 libcdio-paranoia2 libcfitsio7 libcharls2 libchm1 libcinnamon-desktop4 libclang1-8 libclutter-1.0-common libcoarrays-openmpi-dev libcogl-common
  libcolord-gtk1 libcolorhug2 libcolumbus1-common libcolumbus1v5 libcue2 libcxsparse3 libdap25 libdapclient6v5 libdazzle-1.0-0 libdbusmenu-qt2 libdcmtk14 libdecoration0 libdlrestrictions1 libdmapsharing-3.0-2 libdmtx0a libdolphinvcs5 libdouble-conversion1 libdrm-dev libdvbpsi10 libebackend-1.2-10 libebml4v5 libebook-1.2-19
  libebook-contacts-1.2-2 libecal-1.2-19 libedata-book-1.2-25 libedata-cal-1.2-29 libedataserver-1.2-24 libeditorconfig0 libegl-mesa0 libegl1 libegl1-mesa libepsilon1 libepub0 libevdev2 libevent-2.1-6 libevent-core-2.1-6 libevent-pthreads-2.1-6 libfabric1 libfakekey0 libfam0 libfcitx-config4 libfcitx-gclient1 libfcitx-utils0 libfltk1.3
  libfprint0 libframe6 libfreeimage3 libfreexl1 libfyba0 libgail-3-0 libgbm1 libgdal20 libgdata-common libgdata22 libgdbm5 libgdcm2.8 libgdm1 libgeis1 libgeoclue0 libgeonames-common libgeonames0 libgeos-3.7.1 libgeos-c1v5 libgeotiff2 libgif7 libgit2-27 libgjs0g libglapi-mesa libgles1 libgles2 libglpk40 libglvnd-core-dev libglvnd0
  libgnome-autoar-0-0 libgnome-todo libgnomekbd-common libgnomekbd8 libgom-1.0-0 libgphoto2-6 libgphoto2-l10n libgphoto2-port12 libgpod-common libgpod4 libgps23 libgrail6 libgrantlee-templates5 libgraphene-1.0-0 libgraphicsmagick++-q16-12 libgraphicsmagick-q16-3 libgrilo-0.3-0 libgroupsock8 libgsettings-qt1 libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common
  libgsound0 libhavege1 libhdf4-0-alt libhdf5-103 libhdf5-cpp-103 libhdf5-dev libhdf5-openmpi-103 libhfstospell10 libhttp-parser2.8 libhwloc-dev libhwloc-plugins libhwloc5 libibverbs-dev libibverbs1 libido3-0.1-0 libieee1284-3 libimagequant0 libinput-bin libinput10 libixml10 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libjemalloc2 libjpeg-dev
  libjpeg-turbo8-dev libjpeg8-dev libjs-jquery-ui libjsoncpp1 libjxr0 libkaccounts1 libkdecorations2-5v5 libkdecorations2private6 libkdecore5 libkdeui5 libkf5activities5 libkf5activitiesstats1 libkf5archive5 libkf5attica5 libkf5auth-data libkf5balooengine5 libkf5bluezqt-data libkf5bluezqt6 libkf5bookmarks-data libkf5calendarevents5
  libkf5codecs-data libkf5codecs5 libkf5completion-data libkf5config-bin libkf5config-data libkf5configcore5 libkf5configgui5 libkf5configwidgets-data libkf5coreaddons-data libkf5coreaddons5 libkf5dbusaddons-bin libkf5dbusaddons-data libkf5dbusaddons5 libkf5declarative-data libkf5dnssd-data libkf5dnssd5 libkf5doctools5
  libkf5emoticons-data libkf5filemetadata-bin libkf5filemetadata-data libkf5filemetadata3 libkf5globalaccel-data libkf5guiaddons5 libkf5holidays-data libkf5holidays5 libkf5i18n-data libkf5i18n5 libkf5iconthemes-data libkf5itemmodels5 libkf5itemviews-data libkf5jobwidgets-data libkf5js5 libkf5jsapi5 libkf5jsembed-data libkf5kcmutils-data
  libkf5kdcraw5 libkf5kdelibs4support-data libkf5kexiv2-15.0.0 libkf5khtml-data libkf5kiontlm5 libkf5kipi-data libkf5konq-data libkf5networkmanagerqt6 libkf5newstuff-data libkf5notifications-data libkf5notifyconfig-data libkf5package-data libkf5package5 libkf5parts-data libkf5people-data libkf5peoplebackend5 libkf5prison5 libkf5pty-data
  libkf5pty5 libkf5screen-bin libkf5screen7 libkf5service-data libkf5service5 libkf5solid5-data libkf5sonnet5-data libkf5sonnetcore5 libkf5su-data libkf5syndication5abi1 libkf5syntaxhighlighting-data libkf5syntaxhighlighting5 libkf5sysguard-data libkf5texteditor5-libjs-underscore libkf5textwidgets-data libkf5threadweaver5
  libkf5unitconversion-data libkf5unitconversion5 libkf5wallet-data libkf5waylandclient5 libkf5waylandserver5 libkf5widgetsaddons-data libkf5windowsystem-data libkf5xmlgui-bin libkf5xmlgui-data libkf5xmlrpcclient-data libkfontinst5 libkfontinstui5 libkmlbase1 libkmldom1 libkmlengine1 libksgrd7 libkwinglutils12 libkwinxrenderutils12
  libkworkspace5-5 liblapack-dev libldb1 liblightdm-gobject-1-0 liblirc-client0 liblivemedia64 liblmdb0 liblog4cplus-1.1-9 liblua5.2-0 libmad0 libmarkdown2 libmatroska6v5 libmbedcrypto3 libmbedtls12 libmbedx509-0 libmedc11 libmediaart-2.0-0 libmetacity1 libmicrodns0 libminizip1 libmozjs-60-0 libmtdev1 libmtp-common libmtp-runtime
  libmtp9 libmuparser2v5 libmysqlclient20 libncurses-dev libnemo-extension1 libnetcdf-c++4 libnetcdf13 libnfs12 libnl-3-dev libnl-route-3-200 libnl-route-3-dev libnm-glib4 libnm-gtk0 libnm-util2 libnuma-dev libnux-4.0-common liboauth0 libocct-foundation-7.3 libocct-modeling-algorithms-7.3 libocct-modeling-data-7.3 libodbc1 libogdi3.2
  libopencolorio1v5 libopencv-core3.2 libopencv-imgcodecs3.2 libopencv-imgproc3.2 libopencv-videoio3.2 libopengl0 libopenimageio2.0 libopenmpi-dev libopenmpi3 libopenmpt-modplug1 libopenvdb5.2 libpackagekitqt5-1 libpam-fprintd libpam-kwallet-common libpam-kwallet5 libpcre2-16-0 libperl5.26 libphonenumber7 libplacebo7
  libplasma-geolocation-interface5 libpmix2 libpoppler-qt5-1 libpowerdevilui5 libprocesscore7 libproj13 libprotobuf-lite17 libproxy-tools libpsm-infinipath1 libpsm2-2 libpthread-stubs0-dev libpyside2-py3-5.11 libqalculate20 libqalculate20-data libqapt3 libqca-qt5-2 libqca-qt5-2-plugins libqhull7 libqmobipocket2 libqrencode4 libqrupdate1
  libqscintilla2-qt5-l10n libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative libqt4-network libqt4-script libqt4-svg libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns libqt5concurrent5 libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5 libqt5gui5-gles libqt5multimedia5 libqt5network5 libqt5positioning5 libqt5qml5 libqt5script5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5test5 libqt5texttospeech5
  libqt5waylandclient5 libqt5webchannel5 libqt5webengine-data libqt5x11extras5 libqt5xml5 libqt5xmlpatterns5 libqtcurve-utils2 libqtdbus4 libqtgui4 librdmacm1 libre2-5 libreadline-dev librecad-data libresid-builder0c2a libsane-common libscim8v5 libsdl-image1.2 libsdl2-2.0-0 libsgutils2-2 libshiboken2-py3-5.11 libsidplay2 libsignon-glib1
  libsignon-plugins-common1 libsignon-qt5-1 libsmbclient libsnapd-qt1 libsnmp-base libsocket++1 libspatialaudio0 libspatialite7 libspnav0 libspooles2.2 libssh2-1 libsuperlu5 libsysmetrics1 libsz2 libtagc0 libtalloc2 libtbb2 libtevent0 libtext-unidecode-perl libtimezonemap-data libtimezonemap1 libtinyxml2.6.2v5 libtorrent-rasterbar9
  libtracker-control-2.0-0 libtracker-miner-2.0-0 libtracker-sparql-2.0-0 libunity-control-center1 libunity-gtk2-parser0 libunity-gtk3-parser0 libunity-misc4 libunity-settings-daemon1 libupnp13 liburiparser1 liburl-dispatcher1 libusageenvironment3 libva-wayland2 libvlc-bin libvlc5 libvlccore9 libvoikko1 libwayland-server0 libwbclient0
  libwoff1 libwxbase3.0-0v5 libx11-dev libx11-xcb-dev libxapp1 libxatracker2 libxau-dev libxcb-composite0 libxcb-cursor0 libxcb-damage0 libxcb-dpms0 libxcb-dri2-0-dev libxcb-dri3-dev libxcb-glx0 libxcb-glx0-dev libxcb-icccm4 libxcb-image0 libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-present-dev libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-record0 libxcb-render-util0
  libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-res0 libxcb-shape0 libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-sync-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev libxcb-xinerama0 libxcb-xinput0 libxcb-xkb1 libxcb-xv0 libxcb1-dev libxdamage-dev libxdmcp-dev libxerces-c3.2 libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxfont2 libxkbcommon-x11-0 libxklavier16 libxml2-utils libxshmfence-dev libxvmc1 libxxf86dga1
  libxxf86vm-dev libyaml-cpp0.6 libzeitgeist-1.0-1 libzipios++0v5 mesa-common-dev mesa-vulkan-drivers metacity-common mobile-broadband-provider-info mysql-common nautilus-data nemo-data network-manager-gnome octave-common odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 openmpi-bin openmpi-common oxygen-sounds perl-modules-5.26 pgadmin3-data pgagent
  plasma-desktop-data plasma-discover-common policykit-1-gnome powerdevil-data printer-driver-postscript-hp proj-bin proj-data python-matplotlib-data python3-bs4 python3-cycler python3-debconf python3-feedparser python3-html5lib python3-kiwisolver python3-lxml python3-macaroonbakery python3-mako python3-markupsafe python3-matplotlib
  python3-numpy python3-olefile python3-pexpect python3-pil python3-protobuf python3-ptyprocess python3-pyparsing python3-pyside2.qtcore python3-pyside2.qtxml python3-pyside2uic python3-renderpm python3-reportlab python3-reportlab-accel python3-rfc3339 python3-sip python3-soupsieve python3-talloc python3-tz python3-webencodings qdbus
  qdbus-qt5 qml-module-org-kde-bluezqt qml-module-org-kde-kholidays qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel qml-module-qt-labs-settings qml-module-qtqml-models2 qt-at-spi qt5-gtk-platformtheme qt5-image-formats-plugins qtchooser qtspeech5-flite-plugin qttranslations5-l10n ruby-json samba-libs sgml-base sgml-data shiboken2 shotwell-common
  signon-plugin-oauth2 sni-qt socat sonnet-plugins sshfs switcheroo-control tex-common texinfo totem-common tracker tracker-extract tracker-miner-fs tree ubuntu-system-service ubuntu-touch-sounds unity-asset-pool unity-gtk-module-common unity-gtk2-module unity-gtk3-module unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files unity-lens-music
  unity-lens-photos unity-lens-video unity-schemas unity-scope-calculator unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks unity-scope-colourlovers unity-scope-devhelp unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks unity-scope-home unity-scope-manpages unity-scope-openclipart unity-scope-texdoc unity-scope-tomboy unity-scope-video-remote unity-scope-virtualbox
  unity-scope-yelp unity-scope-zotero unity-scopes-master-default unity-scopes-runner unity-services update-notifier-common vlc-bin vlc-data vlc-l10n vlc-plugin-base vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-samba vlc-plugin-video-splitter x11-apps x11-session-utils x11-xkb-utils x11proto-core-dev x11proto-damage-dev x11proto-dev x11proto-fixes-dev
  x11proto-xext-dev x11proto-xf86vidmode-dev xapps-common xfonts-base xfonts-scalable xinit xinput xml-core xorg-sgml-doctools xserver-common xserver-xorg-legacy xtrans-dev yelp-xsl zenity-common zlib1g-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libqt5gui5-gles
Suggested packages:
  qtwayland5 lm-sensors
Recommended packages:
  libqt5svg5
The following packages will be REMOVED
  apturl baloo-kf5 blender bluedevil breeze browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash cheese colord compiz compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-default copyq debconf-kde-helper deja-dup dolphin drkonqi evolution-data-server ffmpegthumbs frameworkintegration freecad freecad-python3 gdm3 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-mutter-4 gir1.2-rb-3.0
  gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gnome-calendar gnome-color-manager gnome-control-center gnome-getting-started-docs gnome-initial-setup gnome-online-accounts gnome-session-bin gnome-shell gnome-shell-extension-appindicator gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock gnome-startup-applications gnome-todo
  gnome-user-docs gnuplot-qt gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse gwenview hplip hud indicator-bluetooth kaccounts-providers kactivitymanagerd kamera kate kde-baseapps kde-cli-tools kde-config-gtk-style kde-config-screenlocker kde-config-sddm kde-plasma-desktop
  kde-spectacle kde-style-breeze kde-style-breeze-qt4 kde-style-oxygen-qt5 kde-style-qtcurve-qt5 kdeconnect kded5 kdegraphics-thumbnailers kdialog kdiff3 keditbookmarks kfind kgamma5 khelpcenter khotkeys kimageformat-plugins kinfocenter kinit kio kio-extras kmenuedit konqueror konsole konsole-kpart kpackagelauncherqml kross krusader
  kscreen ksshaskpass ktexteditor-katepart ktorrent kwalletmanager kwayland-integration kwin-common kwin-style-breeze kwin-x11 kwrite kwrited libavdevice58 libcheese-gtk25 libcheese8 libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-gst-3.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcogl-pango20 libcogl-path20 libcogl20 libcoin80c libcolorcorrect5 libdbusmenu-qt5-2
  libdebconf-kde1 libedataserverui-1.2-2 libfltk-gl1.3 libfreecad-python3-0.18 libgl1 libgl1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libgl2ps1.4 libglew2.1 libglewmx1.13 libglu1-mesa libglvnd-dev libglx-mesa0 libglx0 libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 libhpmud0 libkf5auth5 libkf5authcore5 libkf5baloo5 libkf5baloowidgets-bin
  libkf5baloowidgets-data libkf5baloowidgets5 libkf5bookmarks5 libkf5completion5 libkf5configwidgets5 libkf5crash5 libkf5declarative5 libkf5emoticons-bin libkf5emoticons5 libkf5globalaccel-bin libkf5globalaccel5 libkf5globalaccelprivate5 libkf5iconthemes-bin libkf5iconthemes5 libkf5idletime5 libkf5itemviews5 libkf5jobwidgets5
  libkf5jsembed5 libkf5kcmutils5 libkf5kdelibs4support5 libkf5kdelibs4support5-bin libkf5khtml-bin libkf5khtml5 libkf5kiocore5 libkf5kiofilewidgets5 libkf5kiogui5 libkf5kiowidgets5 libkf5kipi32.0.0 libkf5kirigami2-5 libkf5konq6 libkf5krosscore5 libkf5krossui5 libkf5newstuff5 libkf5newstuffcore5 libkf5notifications5 libkf5notifyconfig5
  libkf5parts-plugins libkf5parts5 libkf5people5 libkf5peoplewidgets5 libkf5plasma5 libkf5plasmaquick5 libkf5plotting5 libkf5purpose-bin libkf5purpose5 libkf5quickaddons5 libkf5runner5 libkf5service-bin libkf5solid5 libkf5sonnetui5 libkf5style5 libkf5su-bin libkf5su5 libkf5texteditor-bin libkf5texteditor5 libkf5textwidgets5
  libkf5wallet-bin libkf5wallet5 libkf5webkit5 libkf5widgetsaddons5 libkf5windowsystem5 libkf5xmlgui5 libkf5xmlrpcclient5 libkscreenlocker5 libktorrent-l10n libktorrent6 libkwalletbackend5-5 libkwin4-effect-builtins1 libkwineffects12 libmutter-4-0 libnux-4.0-0 libocct-data-exchange-7.3 libocct-ocaf-7.3 libocct-visualization-7.3
  liboctave-dev liboctave6 libokular5core9 liboxygenstyle5-5 liboxygenstyleconfig5-5 libphonon4qt5-4 libpolkit-qt5-1-1 libpowerdevilcore2 libprocessui7 libqapt3-runtime libqscintilla2-qt5-13 libqt5designer5 libqt5gui5 libqt5help5 libqt5hunspellinputmethod5 libqt5multimedia5-plugins libqt5multimediagsttools5 libqt5multimediaquick5
  libqt5multimediawidgets5 libqt5opengl5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5quick5 libqt5quickcontrols2-5 libqt5quicktemplates2-5 libqt5quickwidgets5 libqt5svg5 libqt5virtualkeyboard5 libqt5waylandcompositor5 libqt5webengine5 libqt5webenginecore5 libqt5webenginewidgets5 libqt5webkit5 libqt5widgets5 librecad libsane libsane-hpaio libsensors4
  libsnmp30 libsoqt520 libtaskmanager6 libtotem0 libunity-core-6.0-9 libvtk7.1 libweather-ion7 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwxgtk3.0-0v5 libyelp0 mesa-utils milou mutter nautilus nautilus-share nemo nemo-fileroller nux-tools octave okular okular-extra-backends pgadmin3 phonon4qt5 phonon4qt5-backend-vlc plasma-browser-integration
  plasma-dataengines-addons plasma-desktop plasma-discover plasma-discover-snap-backend plasma-framework plasma-integration plasma-pa plasma-widgets-addons plasma-workspace polkit-kde-agent-1 powerdevil printer-driver-hpcups python3-pivy python3-pyqt5 python3-pyside2.qtgui python3-pyside2.qtopengl python3-pyside2.qtsvg
  python3-pyside2.qtuitools python3-pyside2.qtwidgets qapt-batch qbittorrent qml-module-org-kde-activities qml-module-org-kde-draganddrop qml-module-org-kde-kcm qml-module-org-kde-kconfig qml-module-org-kde-kcoreaddons qml-module-org-kde-kio qml-module-org-kde-kirigami2 qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrols
  qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrolsaddons qml-module-org-kde-kwindowsystem qml-module-org-kde-newstuff qml-module-org-kde-purpose qml-module-org-kde-qqc2desktopstyle qml-module-org-kde-runnermodel qml-module-org-kde-solid qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects qml-module-qtmultimedia qml-module-qtquick-controls
  qml-module-qtquick-controls-styles-breeze qml-module-qtquick-controls2 qml-module-qtquick-dialogs qml-module-qtquick-layouts qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets qml-module-qtquick-templates2 qml-module-qtquick-virtualkeyboard qml-module-qtquick-window2 qml-module-qtquick2 qml-module-qtwebengine qml-module-qtwebkit
  qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts qtvirtualkeyboard-plugin qtwayland5 rhythmbox-plugins sane-utils sddm sddm-theme-breeze session-shortcuts shotwell simple-scan software-properties-qt sysstat systemsettings totem totem-plugins ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal ubuntu-docs ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt
  ubuntu-session unity unity-control-center unity-greeter unity-session unity-settings-daemon update-manager update-notifier user-manager vlc vlc-plugin-qt vlc-plugin-skins2 vlc-plugin-video-output vlc-plugin-visualization x11-utils xdg-desktop-portal-kde xorg xserver-xephyr xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all
  xserver-xorg-input-libinput xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-qxl xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware
  xwayland yelp zenity
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libqt5gui5-gles libsensors-config
0 to upgrade, 2 to newly install, 378 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 2,829 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,482 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

Can anyone advise me on what to do here? I don't know what would happen exactly if I tried installing `libsensors-config` since it seems to want to remove `xserver-*`, `ubuntu-*`, `*mesa*` (without reinstalling new versions?) and a whole bunch of other important stuff, but I don't think it'd be good for my system...

**Update 1:**

Here is my sources.list:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ftp.arnes.si/pub/mirrors/ubuntu/ disco main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ftp.arnes.si/pub/mirrors/ubuntu/ disco-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ftp.arnes.si/pub/mirrors/ubuntu/ disco universe
deb http://ftp.arnes.si/pub/mirrors/ubuntu/ disco-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ftp.arnes.si/pub/mirrors/ubuntu/ disco multiverse
deb http://ftp.arnes.si/pub/mirrors/ubuntu/ disco-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.

deb http://ftp.arnes.si/pub/mirrors/ubuntu/ disco-security main restricted
deb http://ftp.arnes.si/pub/mirrors/ubuntu/ disco-security universe
deb http://ftp.arnes.si/pub/mirrors/ubuntu/ disco-security multiverse
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ disco main


deb https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_19.04 ./
# deb-src https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_19.04 ./
```

**Update 2:**

My `apt-cache policy` output (also included `libsensors4` if that helps in any way):

```
$ apt-cache policy sysstat libsensors5 libsensors-config libsensors4
sysstat:
  Installed: 12.0.1-1
  Candidate: 12.0.1-1build1
  Version table:
     12.0.1-1build1 500
        500 http://ftp.arnes.si/pub/mirrors/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
 *** 12.0.1-1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libsensors5:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:3.5.0-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1:3.5.0-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ftp.arnes.si/pub/mirrors/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
libsensors-config:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:3.5.0-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1:3.5.0-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ftp.arnes.si/pub/mirrors/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ftp.arnes.si/pub/mirrors/ubuntu disco/main i386 Packages
libsensors4:
  Installed: 1:3.4.0-4
  Candidate: 1:3.4.0-4
  Version table:
 *** 1:3.4.0-4 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

**Update 3:**

After trying to "manually" download and install the `libsensors5` via `dpkg` I got this:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i --force-all libsensors-config_3.5.0-3ubuntu1_all.deb libsensors5_3.5.0-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package libsensors-config.
dpkg: considering removing libsensors4:amd64 in favour of libsensors-config ...
dpkg: warning: ignoring dependency problem with removal of libsensors4:amd64:
 sysstat depends on libsensors4 (>= 1:3.0.0)
  libsensors4:amd64 is to be removed.

dpkg: warning: ignoring dependency problem with removal of libsensors4:amd64:
 libsnmp30:amd64 depends on libsensors4 (>= 1:3.0.0)
  libsensors4:amd64 is to be removed.

dpkg: warning: ignoring dependency problem with removal of libsensors4:amd64:
 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 depends on libsensors4 (>= 1:3.0.0)
  libsensors4:amd64 is to be removed.

dpkg: yes, will remove libsensors4:amd64 in favour of libsensors-config
(Reading database ... 295245 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libsensors-config_3.5.0-3ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libsensors-config (1:3.5.0-3ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsensors5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack libsensors5_3.5.0-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsensors5:amd64 (1:3.5.0-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libsensors-config (1:3.5.0-3ubuntu1) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/sensors3.conf ...
Setting up libsensors5:amd64 (1:3.5.0-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.29-0ubuntu2) ...


$ sudo apt remove libsensors4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'libsensors4' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Depends: libsensors4 (>= 1:3.0.0) but it is not installable
 libsnmp30 : Depends: libsensors4 (>= 1:3.0.0) but it is not installable
 sysstat : Depends: libsensors4 (>= 1:3.0.0) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).


$ sudo apt -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Depends: libsensors4 (>= 1:3.0.0) but it is not installable
 libsnmp30 : Depends: libsensors4 (>= 1:3.0.0) but it is not installable
 sysstat : Depends: libsensors4 (>= 1:3.0.0) but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

And I still have the same packages held back. `sudo apt upgrade` gives me the same output as `sudo apt -f install`.

However now `libsensors5` and `libsensors-config` seem to be installed?

```
$ apt-cache policy sysstat libsensors5 libsensors-config libsensors4
sysstat:
  Installed: 12.0.1-1
  Candidate: 12.0.1-1build1
  Version table:
     12.0.1-1build1 500
        500 http://ftp.arnes.si/pub/mirrors/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
 *** 12.0.1-1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libsensors5:
  Installed: 1:3.5.0-3ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1:3.5.0-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1:3.5.0-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ftp.arnes.si/pub/mirrors/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libsensors-config:
  Installed: 1:3.5.0-3ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1:3.5.0-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1:3.5.0-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ftp.arnes.si/pub/mirrors/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ftp.arnes.si/pub/mirrors/ubuntu disco/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libsensors4:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
     1:3.4.0-4 -1
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

The new problem is that I can't install any packages now via `apt` since it's always telling me to fix dependency isses `apt --fix-broken install` which doesn't help/fix anything.

**Update 4:**

`apt-cache policy` with just the 3 `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` in the `sources.list` (as per Olimjon's suggestion):

```
$ apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-dri libsnmp30
libgl1-mesa-dri:
  Installed: 19.1~git1904141930.89b02b~oibaf~c
  Candidate: 19.1~git1904141930.89b02b~oibaf~c
  Version table:
 *** 19.1~git1904141930.89b02b~oibaf~c 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     19.0.2-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
libsnmp30:
  Installed: 5.7.3+dfsg-1.8ubuntu3.18.10.1
  Candidate: 5.7.3+dfsg-5ubuntu1
  Version table:
     5.7.3+dfsg-5ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
 *** 5.7.3+dfsg-1.8ubuntu3.18.10.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: I have also upgraded from 18.10 to 19.04, but I do not have your problem. I just installed `sysstat` right now, with no problem and `libsnmp30` was already installed. The current state is like this: `# apt --installed list libsnmp30 sysstat
Listing... Done
libsnmp30/disco,now 5.7.3+dfsg-5ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
sysstat/disco,now 12.0.1-1build1 amd64 [installed]` Have you run `apt autoclean && apt autoremove && apt update && apt dist-upgrade`?

Comment: None of the suggested commands did anything. `dist-upgrade` says there's nothing to upgrade but there are 2 packages that have been kept back (the ones I mention in the question).

Comment: Stupid suggestion, Did you try `sudo apt-get install -f`? As from man page: **-f, --fix-broken Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place. This option, when used with install/remove, can omit any packages to permit APT to deduce a likely solution.**

Comment: I sure have and nothing happens. The command ends with `0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 2 not to upgrade.`, so it's still holding back the 2 packages that depend on `libsensors5` or `libsensors-config`.

Comment: Please, edit the question to provide the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: Done, but I don't think you'll find anything special there.

Comment: @croc, seems OK. Then, please, also add the output of `apt-cache policy sysstat libsensors5 libsensors-config`

Comment: Just for the record: I had similar situation when upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04. In my case, it seemed to be connected to alternative radeon drivers too (oibaf in your case, kisak in mine). I tried to follow the instructions in the accepted answer, but couldn't run `sudo apt remove libsensors4`. In my case, solution was to re-add the mesa ppa (disabled during upgrade?), upgrade everything that was possible, running suggested `apt --fix-broken install`, which did the trick of installing libsensors5 in place of 4 and upgrading again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, you have `libsensors4` package that conflicts with `libsensors-config`. `libsensors4` is even not in the package repository of Disco. So, what you need is to replace `libsensors4` with `libsensors5`:

```
sudo apt update

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lm-sensors/libsensors-config_3.5.0-3ubuntu1_all.deb

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lm-sensors/libsensors5_3.5.0-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i --force-all libsensors-config_3.5.0-3ubuntu1_all.deb libsensors5_3.5.0-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb

sudo apt remove libsensors4

sudo apt -f install
```

### Update 1:

Open `sources.list`:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Remove everything there and add these lines:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates main universe restricted multiverse
```

Save and run:

```
sudo apt update
```

Then try:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

### Update 2:

You have some packages that did not upgrade during the upgrade process.

First of all, remove `sysstat` as you do not need it now:

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-all sysstat
```

Then replace packages with newer version:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libgl1-mesa-dri_19.0.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/n/net-snmp/libsnmp30_5.7.3+dfsg-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i --force-all libsnmp30_5.7.3+dfsg-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb libgl1-mesa-dri_19.0.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb

sudo apt -f install
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm afraid it didn't really work all the way. See my `Update 3` for the new output and I hope you'll have any new suggestions on how to fix that.

Comment: @croc, it is really weird that your system packages depend on a package that does not exist in official repository. Please, also post the output of `apt cache policy libgl1-mesa-dri libsnmp30`. Also, try my new suggestion to replace your `sources.list`.

Comment: I changed the `sources.list` and the only difference is that now it says there are 31 packages that can be upgraded. I still can't install/upgrade anything though because of the unmet deps. problem (`apt upgrade` gives practically the same output as `$ sudo apt -f install` line in **Update 3**). As for the new `apt-cache` output see **Update 4**. Should I just remove (and reinstall?) the 3 packages with unmet deps.? How critical are they to the system?

Comment: @croc, the 3 packages are critical to the system. So, you should reinstall them without removing. BTW, I will show how as an update.

Comment: thanks! That seems to fix the problem :) I have no more held back packages and the system rebooted just fine :P I'm sorry that the bounty expired in the mean time though.

Comment: @croc, glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 2):

### On Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Download the packages `libsensors5` and `libsensors-config` manually from the official Ubuntu repository and force their installation:

```
$ wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lm-sensors/libsensors5_3.6.0-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
$ wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lm-sensors/libsensors-config_3.6.0-2ubuntu1_all.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i --force-all libsensors5_3.6.0-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb libsensors-config_3.6.0-2ubuntu1_all.deb
```

The last command results in the following output:

```
Selecting previously unselected package libsensors5:amd64.
(Reading database ... 655733 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libsensors5_3.6.0-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsensors5:amd64 (1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsensors-config.
dpkg: considering removing libsensors4:amd64 in favour of libsensors-config ...
dpkg: warning: ignoring dependency problem with removal of libsensors4:amd64:
 lm-sensors depends on libsensors4 (>= 1:3.1.1)
  libsensors4:amd64 is to be removed.

dpkg: warning: ignoring dependency problem with removal of libsensors4:amd64:
 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 depends on libsensors4 (>= 1:3.0.0)
  libsensors4:amd64 is to be removed.

dpkg: yes, will remove libsensors4:amd64 in favour of libsensors-config
Preparing to unpack libsensors-config_3.6.0-2ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libsensors-config (1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libsensors-config (1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/sensors3.conf ...
Setting up libsensors5:amd64 (1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.1) ...
```

Finish off with:

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Resulting in:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libegl-mesa0 libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa libglx-mesa0 libosmesa6 lm-sensors
Suggested packages:
  fancontrol read-edid i2c-tools
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libegl-mesa0 libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa libglx-mesa0 libosmesa6 lm-sensors
7 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 1 not to upgrade.
Need to get 12.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 24.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

Comment: thx. fixed it for me.

Answer (score -2):

Run the following commands:

```
sudo apt remove libsensors-config # remove the package
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

If needed run `sudo apt autoremove`