# How to install gnome-control-center on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management

If I try to install I get the following problem:

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-control-center
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 gnome-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk25 (>= 3.18.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese8 (>= 3.28.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libgoa-backend-1.0-1 (>= 3.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: gnome-online-accounts (>= 3.25.3) but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: gnome-user-docs but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I keep installing the dependencies, eventually I reach the following message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Depends: libsensors4 (>= 1:3.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I install libsensors4, and then try and install gnome-control-center again, I get the following:

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-control-center
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libsane : Depends: libsnmp35 (>= 5.8+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: sane-utils (>= 1.0.29-0ubuntu5)
```

Installing libsnmp35 seems to then uninstall libsensors4 and install libsensors5:

```
$ sudo apt install libsnmp35
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libsensors-config libsensors5
Suggested packages:
  lm-sensors
The following packages will be REMOVED
  libsensors4
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libsensors-config libsensors5 libsnmp35
```

I have tried to follow solutions to this problem which I have found here: [libsensors5 or libsensors-config upgrade problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144976/libsensors5-or-libsensors-config-upgrade-problem), for example, but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time when this happens, running 'apt update' first so your repository information is up to date fixes the issue.